# three.js - is it possible to change an loaded .obj object faces' texture dynamically?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

Currently I have a task that would like to show an .obj object on the web
,and the texture of the .obj file should varies through different user input (clicking several
buttons), so I look into three.js.

After finding for solutions in stackoverflow some time, I found that there are some solutions about changing the object texture in a whole, but cannot find out solutions for particularly of a single face (For example, if the obj is a cube, then just change the texture of the front face). I would need to do that since the texture of different faces in the obj is different

Is is possible to change an loaded .obj object's texture for one face only dynamically? If yes, what would be the trick?

===========================
Updated:
Now my .obj object is a cubeman like the game *Minecraft* player character (reference image if you do not know what it is: [http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/**cb20130604003021/p**/protagonist/images/5/52/Minecraft-steve_12.png](http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130604003021/p__/protagonist/images/5/52/Minecraft-steve_12.png))

I have import the .obj file from the OBJLoader that comes with the three.js example:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
 loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.position.x = 0;
    object.position.y = 0;
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

I would like to the know the way that can change different faces' texture of the object, as like to change the cloth / face skin of the character. The texture are required to be changed independently since the texture of cloth and face  can be change independently.

Comment: This is possible, but it depends on a lot of factors. Can you show a live example, or at least how your mesh is being loaded and instantiated? Do you know what face you want to change, or is that part of the question? I assume you are using WebGLRender?

Comment: There are surely purely good programmatic approaches. But an alternative method I often use, is I paint each face (that is likely to need invidual material change) with different material (color) in the modelling tool. Since I'm gonna replace the material in Three.js anyway, this way I made it easy when each face or face group has a unique material assigned to it. It is then easy to just adjust a material, add textures, or make them identical with other faces/materials. As a bonus it's easy to see which faces are which as they are represented with different colors in the modelling program.

Comment: @WestLangle Yes I am using WebGLRender. Currently I am just loading the .obj file through THREE.OBJLoader to load the obj into the scene.You may think that my object is some combination of cubes (to make my question simplier but it's actually more than that), and I want each face of the cubes can change their texture independently according to user input

Comment: @passer ... then each face (pair of triangles) needs to have it's own material. Search for `MeshFaceMaterial( materials ).` This can be slow if there are a lot of faces/materials. How many faces are you dealing with?

Comment: @WestLangle Since I am now trying to figure out the approach first so  in this stage I am just trying to import some cube-based object. So, I think there will not be too many faces

Comment: You are going to have to show a live example of your problem and ask a specific question about it. There are many peices to this puzzle, and I do not know what part of it you do not know how to do.

Comment: @WestLangle Well actually I have no idea on what I am going to do after loading the obj into the canvas ^ ^; . I have updated my question so you can take I look on what I want to do now.